# How to get an accurate [M]=> value from the Google Search Appliance API with PHP?

Tags: php, google-search-api, google-search-appliance

I'm getting inaccurate number of search results using GSA, I have read this [article](http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/current/gsa_doc_set/xml_reference/appendices.html#1075478), but am not sure where to use "rc=1" or if I even want to (because of the possible latency issues). This is what I have right now and $totalItems is only getting the [M] value for the first [M] value which appears to be inaccurate. For example the first page of results yields [M] => 66 and the last page of results yields [M] => 42 (which is correct), here is a bit of my code:

```
$url = 'https://search.state.edu/search?q='.$q.'&client='.$client.'&output='.$form.'&oe=UTF-8&ie=UTF-8&ud=1'.(is_null($sort) ? "" : "&sort=$sort").'&site='.$site.'&access=p&entqr=3&entqrm=0&start='.$start.'&limit='.$limit.''.'&getfields=thumbnail';
$result = simplexml_load_file($url);
$totalItems = $result->RES->M;
```

Where would I insert "rc=1" in the query or is there a way to pull all records so I can search for the last [M] (which seems to be accurate)?

How do other people deal with this inaccuracy?

First [M]:

```
[RES] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [@attributes] => Array
            (
                [SN] => 1
                [EN] => 10
            )

        [M] => 66
```

The last [M]:

```
[RES] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [@attributes] => Array
            (
                [SN] => 41
                [EN] => 42
            )

        [M] => 42
```

Answer (score 2):

rc parameter is indeed the one you need to get the accurate number of results.

But if you use the default filter value, some results will be filtered and you won't see that much results.

You could try to combine both &rc=1&filter=0 in your query string.

Please note with filter=0 you'll the following disabled :

- Directory filtering (filtering documents coming from the same folder)
- Duplicate snipper filtering (if two documents have the same snippet generated, it will be filtered)

Comment: Interesting the &rc=1&filter=0 provided new "expanded" results  as did just using &filter=0 both results displayed == the [M] value. Is there a benefit to using both parameters?

Comment: using filter=0 is a good idea as it stops the nesting of similar results which often confuses users as they don't understand the reasons for the nesting.

Comment: Yes, higher the number of results get, estimate gets less accurate

Answer (score 0):

Like 'q' and 'client' and 'output', 'rc' is also yet another parameter. So just add 'rc' as another parameter/query-string and default the value to 1. Something like this,

```
$url = 'https://search.state.edu/search?q='.$q.'&client='.$client.'&output='.$form.'&oe=UTF-8&ie=UTF-8&ud=1'.(is_null($sort) ? "" : "&sort=$sort").'&site='.$site.'&access=p&entqr=3&entqrm=0&start='.$start.'&limit='.$limit.''.'&getfields=thumbnail&rc=1';
```

> > or if I even want to (because of the possible latency issues).

rc=1 will give you the exact count as against the approximate count. Requesting for the exact count instead of approximate count will add performance overhead. So using it only if absolutely necessary is recommended.

You call it 'inaccurate'. Google calls it 'approximate'. Its all how we see it!

Comment: Hmm I just tried this and am still receiving 66 results. See update to question...